# Hive date (field name - trans_dt) conversion from "YYYYMMDD" to "YYYY-MM-DD" (field name - dt) and querying based on the newly created field

Tags: date, hive, format

I am trying to query data for yesterday (or last 24 hrs) in Hive but the filter trans_dt>=date_sub(current_date(),1) only works when the trans_dt format is "YYYY-MM-DD".  The current format of trans_dt is "YYYYMMDD" and so I am converting it to "YYYY-MM-DD" by using the below concat command.

select concat(substring(trans_dt,1,4),'-',substring(trans_dt,5,2),'-',substring(trans_dt,7,2)) as dt from xyz

But now I am not sure how to add the ">=date_sub(current_date(),1)" condition on the newly created field "dt".  Its failing as it is not a field in the table.

I am new to this querying in Hive and am not sure if I am totally off and there is an easier way?  Please advise.  All my online searches have only told me that there is no direct function in Hive to convert the date format from "YYYYMMDD" to "YYYY-MM-DD".

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this one?

```
CAST(CAST( trans_dt AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS DATE format 'YYYY-MM-DD') as TRANS_DATE
```

using CAST can be the solution for changing the date format